# If one UL already is opened, hide the other one, how?

Tags: jquery

So, I'm creating a submenu by myself by following the jQuery codex only and I got stuck. Everything else is perfect, though.

I have an HTML structure like the following:

```
<li><a href="#">smth</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">smth sub</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">smth</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">smth sub 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

And let's say that the first SMTH is opened. Now, when I click on the second SMTH it will just appear on top of the other one.

My jQuery code is as follows.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /*
    * header navigation
    */

    // hide sub UL's
    $('ul.sub').hide();

    $('#header .left li.m:first a, #header .right li.m:first a').css('borderLeft', 'none');
    $('#header .left li.m:last a, #header .right li.m:last a').css('borderRight', 'none');

    // Add class closed, because it's nessesery.
    $('#header .left li ul').addClass('closed');

    // If LI element is clicked, open or close sub UL?
    $('#header .left li').click(function(event)
    {
        // If sub UL is closed, we need to open it.
        if( $(this).find('ul').hasClass('closed') )
        {
            $(this).find('ul').removeClass('closed');
            $(this).find('ul').addClass('opened');
            $(this).find('ul').fadeIn('100');
        }
        // If sub UL is opened, we need to close it.
        else
        {
            $(this).find('ul').removeClass('opened');
            $(this).find('ul').addClass('closed');
            $(this).find('ul').fadeOut('100');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using a plugin (for example, [Superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/))?

Comment: you do know that one of the things that's make jQuery lovely is chaining right? f.ex. `$(this).find('ul').removeClass('opened').addClass('closed').fadeOut('100');`

Comment: @Matt if I always use a plugin for everything, I never learn anything.

Comment: @balexandre yeah I know, i guess I forgot that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I got the image right, because I don't know how you're styling your menu, so I'll assume it's a vertical list of SMTHs with sublists showing to the right.

What you want to do is close all opened sublists (this will normally be only one sublist) when you click on the SMTH, before you add the "opened" class.

This is how I'd modify your code:

```
    // ...

    // if LI element is clicked, open or close sub UL?
    $('#header .left li').click(function(event)
    {
      // if sub UL is closed, we need to open it
      if( $(this).find('ul').hasClass('closed') )
      {
        // close all opened sublists
        $('ul.opened')
          .removeClass('opened')
          .addClass('closed')
          .fadeOut('100');

        // ...
```

Also, Ben Roux's switchClass advice is great, you should consider it.

Comment: I didn't quite master the switchClas thingy because it had no effect what-so-ever, I guess my code is just too damaged for that power. But your solution worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. As Frédéric Hamidi mentioned in the comments on Ben's answer, "[switchClass] is provided by jQuery UI, not by the core toolkit". You'd need to include the jQuery UI script if you wanted to use that method.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. I guess that's what I get when reading with a hurry. I'll check that out later too, again. And thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that your click function is showing and hiding the element you clicked on properly, but it is not hiding all other ul's that may be open already. Consider making the first line something like:

```
$(".subNav").switchClass( "open", "closed", 100 );
```

Which brings up a good point as well. JQuery has a switchClass() function that is nearly identical to your 3 lines of remove -> add -> fade. A great way to save some lines of code.

EDIT: I should also note that the line of js I wrote here requires that you add a class to all of your ul's that are for sub navigation. There are other ways to do this, but for the purpose of easy explanation, this seemed most fitting.

Comment: +1 for `switchClass()`, but note that method is provided by jQuery UI, not by the core toolkit.